# Creating Radiogroup programmeticly in android

Tags: radio-button, radio-group

I am trying to run my app which is having multiple android radiogroup and radiobutton but my code showing error

```
RadioButton rd[]=new RadioButton[Remarks.length()];
            RadioGroup rdg[]=new RadioGroup[Attribute.length()];
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams params;
            params=new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            for (int j = 0; j < Remarks.length(); j++) {
                rd[j].setId(j+i+1);
                rd[j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablelines);
                rdg[i].addView(rd[j], params);
                tr.addView(rdg[i]);
            }
```